# Returning date if date column and string "-" when null, and still pass to front as date, not string

Tags: mysql, angularjs

Tried to summarize in title as much as possible, but probably not so clear.

Here it is.

I have a query having outer join returning a date column. So, I will have 'empty date' in the result rows. For this I handle with ifnull() to change that emptiness into " - ".

Problem is that column cannot be processed at the front-end using like `{{order.LastDateOrder | date : "dd-MMMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"}}`. When the column contains data, it is shown in format like '`2017-06-05 07:27:50`' while actually what I want is to show it like `'05 June 2017 07:27:50'`. The `null` values, should be shown as `" - "`.

What are the alternatives to achieve what I want?

(I am using MySQL, and Angular)

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend entirely handling the formatting on the MySQL side of things.  Consider the following query:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    COALESCE(DATE_FORMAT(t2.col, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'), '-') AS date_label
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
```

Then, on the Angular side, just display a basic string, with no special formatting needed.

The jist of my approach is that we convert your date column to the string format you want, but if `NULL` we just replace with a dash.  And we do this within MySQL where we can easily handle `NULL` values using `COALESCE`.

Answer (score 0):

I have created custom filter name as formatDate and in your view you can use it as `{{order.LastDateOrder | formatDate}}`. Hope it will help you.

```
angular.module('test').filter('formatDate', function () {
    return function (date) {
        var mydate = new Date(date);
        var month=["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
        ];
        return mydate.getDate() +  month[mydate.getMonth()] +  mydate.getFullYear() + mydate.getHours()+ mydate.getMinutes()+ mydate.getSeconds();

    }
})
```